# AngularJS ui-router Do not load <section>

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My router

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
function($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
//

  $stateProvider
    .state("dashboard",  {
          url: '/dashboard',
          templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
          controller: 'dashboard'
    })
    //
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
  }
]);
```

My dashboard.html

```
<section class="hbox stretch">
  <section>
    <section class="vbox">
      <section class="scrollable padder">
        <section class="row m-b-md">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h3 class="m-b-xs text-black">Dashboard</h3>
            <small>Welcome back, Rene Lima, <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg text-primary"></i> New York City</small>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-right text-left-xs m-t-md">
            <a href="#nav, #sidebar" class="btn btn-icon b-2x bg-info lt btn-rounded" data-toggle="class:nav-xs, show"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
          </div>
        </section>

      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

I have in my index.html in the block of code

```
  <section id="content">
      <div ui-view=""></div>
  </section>
```

But do not load the dashboard.html page.
If I swap the `<session>` tags with `<div>` works perfectly, what is this?

Comment: you mean `<section>` and not `<session>`, right ?

Comment: Yes!!!!! Sorry, thank you